# how to aggregate sub document in mongodb?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a the following collection :

```
{
    name: "c1",
    jobs: [{
        category: "a"
    }, {
        category: "a"
    },{
        category: "b"
    }]
}
{
    name: "c2",
    jobs: [{
        category: "b"
    }, {
        category: "c"
    }]
}
```

and i want to get the following result:

```
[{
    category: "a",
    total: 2
}, {
    category: "b",
    total: 2
}, {
    category: "c",
    total: 1
}]
```

How i can do this with mongodb query (or even better with mongodb c# driver)?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.test.aggregate( 
    { $unwind: "$jobs" }, 
    { $group: 
        { _id: '$jobs.category', total : { '$sum' : 1 } } 
    },
    { $project: { category : '$_id', _id:0, total:1 } }     
).toArray()
```

This produces exactly the result as in your question.

1. Five Documents will be produces by unwinding the category array
2. For each category, the amount is counted
3. The _id from the $group step is renamed to category
4. The result set converted into an array

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate( 
    { $unwind: "$jobs" }, 
    { $group: 
        { _id: '$jobs.category', total : { '$sum' : 1 } } 
    } 
)
```